# Is it any free ebooks/publications of ros is available

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey..  I'm sorry for this non-technical question

Recently I'm searching any ebooks/printed(for beginners) available to study ros. I know that ros website contain more than enough information. But I am very much prefer if some tutorial ebooks/printed books are available.

Please share me if any such are available.
Is it any good tutorial videos are available?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/57370/is-it-any-free-ebooks/publications-of-ros-is-available/) by [unais](https://answers.ros.org/users/4285/unais/) on ROS Answers with karma: 313 on 2013-03-06

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Regarding books: it is a duplicate question of [#9797](http://answers.ros.org/question/9797/are-there-any-books-on-ros/). Please see [this answer](http://answers.ros.org/question/9797/are-there-any-books-on-ros/?answer=42412#post-id-42412).

---

Originally posted by [Boris](https://answers.ros.org/users/2873/boris/) with karma: 3060 on 2013-03-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2